# Add two legend title ( one for line and another for ribbon)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add one title to my legend. The argument "fill" and "color" have the same variable : varC (14 factors). I try to do this with :

```
g.mean <- ggplot(df,aes(x = as.numeric(xx),y=yy,color=varc)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Born_Inf, ymax=Born_Sup, fill=varc), alpha=0.1) + 
  guides(color= guide_legend("My title for line"),fill=guide_legend("My title for ribbon"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `guides` and try one of the following. The reason I give two possible answers is because I cannot be 100% sure exactly which will work without seeing a sample of your data. If `varc` is a `factor` or `character` the second one should work, if it is `numeric` the first one should work.

**1.**

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = as.numeric(xx),y=yy,color=varc)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Born_Inf, ymax=Born_Sup, fill=varc), alpha=0.1) +   
  scale_color_continuous(name = "My title for line") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "My title for ribbon")
```

**2.**

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = as.numeric(xx),y=yy,color=varc)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Born_Inf, ymax=Born_Sup, fill=varc), alpha=0.1) +   
  scale_color_discrete(name = "My title for line") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "My title for ribbon")
```

Comment: I have already try to add the following rows but the results is the same as my picture.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I need to print my ggplot's object in style() function. I  edit my post ...

Comment: @CoxTox I suggest you post this as a new question as I don't think anyone will see this now. Unfortunately I can't help you with this problem.